# Using Rails and Devise, I want to send a welcome email on sign up.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise

How can I send a welcoming email to the user when they sign up? I'm using the Devise gem for authentication. SMTP is already set up. I just need to understand how to extend devise to send emails.

NOTE - this is not confirmation email!

**UPD Solution:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :send_welcome_email 

  private

    def send_welcome_email
      UserMailer.deliver_welcome_email(self)
    end
end
```

Comment: How can I send the welcome message "after" it has confirmed the account? (in restful_authentication there was a method called recently_activated?)

Comment: Your updated solution was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a callback (after_create ) in the model or observer to send the email using normal mailer methods.

Answer (score 6):

FYI, in Rails 3 it's:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :send_welcome_email 

  private

    def send_welcome_email
      UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
    end 
end
```