# Send a welcome email after the user has confirmed his account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

I am using devise and actionmailer. I am wondering how do I trigger an actionmailer method after the user has confirmed his account on the app and not before This actionmailer method is nothing but a welcome message.

Also, how do I fetch that sames users info, like name or email? I tried `resource`. But it didn't work.

Comment: googling for `after confirmation devise` turns up some good articles so you may want to start with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a relatively easy task. All you need to do is create an [Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) for your User class.

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    def after_save(user)            
        if user.confirmed_at_changed?
            #send email
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Because Observers have been moved to their own gem as of Rails 4, and for reasons detailed in [this article](http://www.samuelmullen.com/2013/05/the-problem-with-rails-callbacks), I would look to an alternative to Observers.

Answer (score 1):

[Rails 3: Send welcome e-mail using Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553586/rails-3-send-welcome-e-mail-using-devise/6133991#6133991) has a good answer
you can do something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise # ...
  # ...
  def confirm!
    welcome_message # define this method as needed
    super
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: yes but it sends along with the confirmation email. Thats not what I want. I want it to be sent `after` the user has confirmed his/her account

Answer (score 1):

This did it.

```
after_save :send_welcome_email
  def send_welcome_email
    WelcomeEmail.notify(self).deliver if self.confirmed_at_changed?
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Devise has a built in callback for this scenario.

```
    # A callback initiated after successfully confirming. This can be
    # used to insert your own logic that is only run after the user successfully
    # confirms.
    #
    # Example:
    #
    #   def after_confirmation
    #     self.update_attribute(:invite_code, nil)
    #   end
    #
    def after_confirmation
    end
```

You can find the code in devise/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb

Answer (score 0):

Using after_save would make your application run and check the condition whether the user was confirmed just now. That would lead to an unnecessary delay.

I recommend overriding the default confirm function provided by devise using the following code.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
         :rememberable, :confirmable, :validatable, :encryptable

  # Override devise confirm! message
  def confirm!
    welcome_email
    super
  end

  # ...

private

  def welcome_email
    UserMailer.welcome_message(self).deliver
  end

end
```

http://csnipp.com/s/507/-Send-welcome-mail-after-confirmation-devise